# What does the small text say in the noitaminA intro?

Tags: anime-production

At the start of noitaminA animes, there is a loading screen with lots of text appearing onscreen.

[image]

Looking closer, I noticed mentions of Eden of the East , Monokoe and Tales of Agriculture - so I reckon there are some Easter Eggs hidden in the rest of the text also.

Unfortunately, all the images I have found are too low resolution to make out what they say.

Can anyone reveal the super-secret messages that lie in noitaminA's loading screen?

Comment: Interesting can also see that, tough you were referring to the black'n'white letters at first.

Comment: I see that noitaminA is a programming block for TV stations that consists of mostly anime over in Japan. I also see that they most of the windows have anime titles on it like Tokyo ESP and The Tatami Galaxy along with large blocks of text. I think they might just be summaries of the anime.

Comment: There's some 720 versions of the image, but any BD release has that splash screen removed. The best I can make out is some text about noitaminA (maybe from their website) and a bunch of stuff about other shows, Tatami Galaxy, a list of broadcasted anime, air schedules. Maybe some graphs just for "looks"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With thanks to user @Prix for linking this to me, and reddit user herrekorre for the actual content.

Here is a higher resolution image:

[image]

[image]

I think this section is fairly easy to read.

> noitaminA jingle movie - TYPE: Augmented Reality (ar) Version 1.10.03.23
>
> (b) 2010 made by Studio - RIKKA.
>
> No drive attached to Animation, The BIOS is not installed.
>
> Checking file system on C:
>
> The type of file system is Augmented Reality.
>
> CHKDSK is verifying files ( stage 1 of 1 ).
>
> File verification completed.
>
> 100 percent completed

[image]

> Expanding "noitaminA" timeslot
>
> Set at Thursday 24:45-25:15, noitaminA has been the highest rated midnight anime slot on TV in Japan.
>
> Stable and high reputations gained from the advertisers.
>
> Starting April 2010, the 30-min weekly timeslot
>
> **TALES OF AGRICULTURE**
>
> Tadayasu is a new fresh-faced university student hiding a bizarre secret: He can see germs with the naked eye.
>
> **EDEN OF THE EAST**
>
> Set in Tokyo in the near future, this is a story of just 11 days on a boy who challenged the prevailing "depressing" mood of the country and a girl who supported him.
>
> **MONONOKE**
>
> In the Edo era of Japan, as cultural arts, modern science, and technology flourished, so too did the practice of mystical arts, as humanity faced the perils of the supernatural!

(Mononoke script found at: http://www.fujicreative.co.jp/Portals/0/special/anime/mononoke/mononoke.html)

[image]

> NOTICE!
>
> magnitude8
>
> The location is Odaiba, the Tokyo Bay Area at the start of the summer vacation
>   13-year-old Mirai and her 8-year-old brother, Yuki, are left away from home when the catastrophically large quake has hit Tokyo.
>
> EDEN OF THE EAST
>
> Set in Tokyo in the near future, this is a story of just 11 days on a boy who challenged the prevailing "depressing" mood of the country and a girl who supported him. The boy, Takizawa, who lost his memory, helps Saki out when she is trouble in Washington D.C. They return to Japan and try to solve the mysteries of Takizawa's lost memory. He seems to be one of the twelve selected people to lead the country in the right direction.

[image]

> **STATUS**
>
> Starting April 2010, the 30-min weekly timeslot will be expanded into one hour
>
> **LEVEL1**
>
> - Format: 12(?)eps, 30min
> - broadCast:from April22
> - Timeslot: "noitaminA"

Similar info for Level 2 & 3

[image]

> Expanding "noitaminA" timeslot
>
> Set at Thursday 24:45-25:15, noitaminA has been the highest rated midnight anime slot on TV in Japan.
>
> Stable and high reputations gained from the advertisers.
>
> Starting April 2010, the 30-min weekly timeslot will be expanded into one hour consisting of two 30min series, doubling the number of animation titles to be produced and broadcast in the slot throughout the year.

[image]

> TITLE
>
> ---
>
> The Tatami Galaxy
>
> TALES OF AGRICULTURE
>
> Saraiya Goyou
>
> Welcom to Irabu's_office
>
> EDEN OF THE EAST
>
> magunitude8
>
> Antique
>
> Hakaba_kitano
>
> MONONOKE
>
> Genji

[image]

> Antique
>
> One day Keichiro Tachibana opens a cake shop. Then a gifted patissier/pastry chef called Ono appears. Tachibana and Ono were classmates in high school, but Tachibana gave Ono (a man) the cold shoulder back then. Luckily Ono doesn't remember Tachibana. Tachibana feels relaxed and persuades Ono to work for him as a chef/patissier. However, Ono is a guy of "irresistible Charm" now and gives Tachibana nightmares by trying to seduce him.
>   At this cake shop called Antique, an incident from Tachibana's childhood is revealed, and a variety of cakes is presented. This is a delightful comedy anime

I'm sure it's missing stuff here and there, but this solves the mystery of the small text. It's mainly synopses and similar small items of text related to noitaminA.

Most of the extraction of info:  http://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/23ac5m/does_anyone_have_a_transcription_of_the_text_from/

Answer (score 4):

Odd that you mention it, because it seems that Studio Rikka (of *Pale Cocoon* and *Time of Eve* fame) was released in the production. The particular UI is done in the style of Time of Eve. No, this probably doesn't mean Time of EVE II is confirmed.

It says, on the top left:

> noitaminA jingle movie - TYPE: Augemented Reality (ar) Version 1.10.03.23
> (b) 2010 made by Studio Rikka.
>
> No drive attached to Animation, The BIOS is not installed.
>
> Checking files system C:
> The type of the file system is Augmented Reality.
>
> CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 1)...
> File Verification completed.
> 100 percent completed.

The bottom right says:

> (A, {{backwards R}} logo img) 拡張現実 (augmented reality) AUGUMENT REARTY

[image: Studio Rikka in Noitamina]

Answer (score 2):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0stiWHFrxoc

also check this, the animated intro backwards (or the same: original status of the recording) says Back to Marijuana. #LOL

Comment: Astonishingly, this is not a fabrication by the uploader. It actually does say "back to marijuana" (or something remarkably similar), reversed - I checked with pristine audio, myself. This is a remarkably amusing fact, but I'm not sure it constitutes an answer to OP's question.

Comment: just a fun fact, really :)